# AS3 - Fast search through array with strings

Tags: arrays, performance, actionscript-3, search

I need help. I am making something like dictionary (but you are filling it by yourself). I need fast search for words in it. I need to use Object or Array (because Dictionary is not supported by JSON. There is option to save file). I have this code, but I am afraid it is not so optimized to search fast when there will be a lot of words in array. Please help.

```
public function Search (string:String,section:String = Wordbook.NEWW):int
    {
        var str:String = string.toUpperCase();
        for (i = 0; i < NewWords.length; i++)
        {
            if (NewWords[i].toUpperCase.indexOf(str) > -1)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;//If not found
    }
```

And example how it should work: (SearchTxt - text field, user should type here word he need to find; WB - Wordbook class; WB.NewWords & WB.NewWordsT - Arrays in this class)

```
var index:int = WB.Search(SearchTxt.text,Wordbook.NEWW);
if(index>-1){
  WordTxt.text = WB.NewWords[index];
  TranslationTxt.text = WB.NewWordsT[index];
} else {
  dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.ERROR,{error:"No match!"}));
}
```

Comment: Why would a `Dictionary` be any faster for this? It doesn't include  any special search features, it just forces strict equality testing

Comment: @CyanAngel Okay. Thanks for a pearl of wisdom, but maybe you have another one, that will help me? :)

Comment: Add a small sample of the data your searching through and search criteria you might expect. I'm no expect in search optimisation, but such samples will make it easier for those who might know something

Comment: @CyanAngel is it better now? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No I mean an example of whats in `WB.Words` and what you'd expect to be in `SearchTxt.text`

Comment: @CyanAngel now better? :) I thought it was understandable

Comment: It's a bit clearer now yes, so your looking for whole words & not sub-strings?

Comment: @CyanAngel both. Whole words and substrings.

Comment: Do you need to support all substrings or only word beginnings (e.g. "wo" could match "world", "wolf", but you don't have to worry about matching "reword")?

Comment: @Brian only word beginnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions here, depending on your use-cases.

Solution 1:  **Leave it alone!**

If the biggest dictionary you're going to build is only a hundred words or so, performance will be fine with a linear search.

Solution 2:  **Implement a binary search algorithm**

If you do need to deal with large dictionaries of thousands of words, a binary search algorithm will offer improved performance.  For this, you'll need to guarantee that your search array is sorted.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public function Search (string:String,section:Array = NewWords, offset:int = 0):int
{
    if (section.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    var str:String = string.toUpperCase();
    var firstCharCode:int = str.charCodeAt(0);
    var middleWord:String = section[section.length / 2];
    var middleWordCharCode:int = middleWord.charCodeAt(0);


    if (middleWord.substr(0,str.length) == str) {
        return (section.length / 2) + offset;
    } else {
        var comparison:int = str.localeCompare(middleWord);
        if (comparison < 0) {
            return Search(string, section.splice(0, section.length / 2), offset);
        } else { // then comparison > 0
            var newOffset:int = offset + section.length / 2;
            return Search(string, section.splice(section.length / 2, section.length-1), newOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, dictionaries are filled by users of app, so I don't know how much words there will be :) So sorted array and this code will be my solution?

Comment: @HarrySky, you could also check the length of the array and use a linear search if it's a short array (doing some testing will let you  know where that cutoff is).

Comment: I sorted array, but it throws error when your code is running. Throws after it goes to another circle. Why it doesn't work? Could you help please :c

Comment: Thanks to you! I googled linear and binary search and found solution. May force be with you :)